# MediaWiki API and encoding

Tags: encoding, mediawiki, diacritics

I'm using the [MediaWiki API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to update some pages with an experimental robot.
This robot uses the Java Apache HTTP-client library to update the pages.

```
(...)
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://mymediawikiinstallation/w/api.php");
postMethod.addParameter("action","edit");
postMethod.addParameter("title",page.replace(' ', '_'));
postMethod.addParameter("summary","trying to fix this accent problem");
postMethod.addParameter("text",content);
postMethod.addParameter("basetimestamp",basetimestamp);
postMethod.addParameter("starttimestamp",starttimestamp);
postMethod.addParameter("token",token);
postMethod.addParameter("notminor","");
postMethod.addParameter("format","xml");
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
(...)
```

However the 'content' string contains some accents. `System.out.prinln(content)` looks OK, but the accentuated characters in the wiki look bad. E.g.  'Val�rie' instead of 'Valérie'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, changing the request header fixed the problem.

```
postMethod.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my PHP code to talk to the Mediawiki API I used [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) to encode the title parameter, and this seems to work fine.

Comment: Hi Roderic :-)
Thanks but, I don't think this is the problem. The 'addParameters' methods already converts the data when it sends the POST query. May be the solution is here: http://tinyurl.com/lyxv8c. I'll check tomorrow.